# Is punishment or retribution without proper application of a defence intrinsically unjust?

Tags: philosophy-of-law, justice, justice-as-fairness

Is punishment or retribution without proper application of a defence intrinsically unjust? If you won't do what the defendent says will prove his innocence, then is it unfair punishment *even if you are right that he is guilty*?

In the example I am thinking of, Smith is being taken to court for something he has an alibi for. Smith tried to prove the alibi was sound, but failed to do so right away, and is now being denied any further opportunity to show where he was and at what time. Leaving aside his innocence (he assures us he is innocent), is this unjust or unfair?

Does this link to the idea of "innocent until proven guilty"? And is punishment ever ok if you have not proven guilt?

Comment: Smith seems to get in to a lot of trouble lately.